# CartoDB createLayer function not working

Tags: google-maps, carto

I'm using `cartodb.js` on my website and it were working fine. But couple of days ago I found that `cartodb layer` is not loading properly. When I check the console in `Firefox`, I found this error

```
ReferenceError: functionreturn_cdbc_cartodb is not defined
```

I search on google but there exist no suggestions. Clicking on error show

```
functionreturn_cdbc_cartodb.uniqueCallbackNameJSON.stringifyt.toJSON({
"layergroupid": "an_id_written_here",
"cdn_url": {
    "http": "ashbu.cartocdn.com",
    "https": "cartocdn-ashbu.global.ssl.fastly.net"
},
"last_updated": "2014-10-29T05:03:33.820Z"
});
```

This is how I'm adding my layer

```
 cartodb.createLayer(map, url)
 .addTo(map).on('done', function(layer) {
 def=layer})
```

Another thing is, I'm using same way to add layers on other pages of my website and this function is working properly on those pages. I'm using `google maps` for base maps.

Any suggestions would be warmly welcome.

Comment: could you share an example so I can check the problem?

Comment: do you want the webpage link where this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the Question that I'm using same way to add layers on other pages and the code is working fine there.

So, I started debugging my page line by line and found that I had added `Jquery` twice in the page. Removing one link of `Jquery` resolved above mentioned problem.